# how does vb.net handle multiple versions of the same dll

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a website written 5 years ago in asp.net 2.0 and vb.net 2005 and visual studio 2005

The website uses a data access layer written using subsonic. The DAL is a class library which imports the subsonic dll. It also needs to import the mysql.data dll to connect to an underlying mysql database. Subsonic needs  a specific version of the mysql.data connector (5.2.2) and so this is the version the class library imports.

The website also uses a custom membership provider for mysql. This is another class library which mysql.data dll version 6.5.4

The website uses both the DAL and the custom membership provider and so imports the dlls for both of these class files. I'm confused how it can handle the 2 different versions of the mysql data connector used by these class libraries

The web.config file has this line

```
<add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/></assemblies>
```

If i delete this line and then rebuild the website the line appears again.

The website also has a copy of the mysql.data 5.2.2 dll in the bin directory. If i delete this file and then rebuild the website the file appears again. In other words the name of the dll appears in the bin directory in the explorer window of visual studio and the physical file appears in the bin directory of the website.

I would really like to know what is going on here and how vb.net can use 2 versions of the same dll. Everything seems to be working ok but the components in this website are so old that they are unsupported. I really don't want to break anything and then not be able to fix it.

Thanks a lot